# Draw Background

Tags: java, graphics

Hey guys can anybody tell me why my background is not drawing

```
    background = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Aiden Strydom\\Desktop\\Java Game\\Images\\background.jpg").getImage();
}

@Override
public synchronized void DrawScreen(Graphics2D g) 
{
    int Width = screen.getWidth();
    int Height = screen.getHeight();

    ImageLocation.x %= Width;  //Make image wrap around  
    ImageLocation.y %= Height;

    if(ImageLocation.x < 0)
        ImageLocation.x += Width;
    if(ImageLocation.y < 0)
        ImageLocation.y += Height;

    int x = ImageLocation.x;
    int y = ImageLocation.y;

    g.drawImage(background, x, y, null);
    g.drawImage(background, x - Width, y, null);
    g.drawImage(background, x, y - Height, null);
    g.drawImage(background, x - Width, y - Height, null);
}
```

I just see the default grey screen, and the debugger does hit the g.drawImage method!

Update: Actually nothing wrong with the code - some how the background picture got deleted out of the folder - when i created a new background picture it Worked.

Comment: Learn and use standard java naming conventions. Method and variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: @camickr - firstly today is my first time coding in Java - and secondly - that is the way i type and that is not going to change.

Don't try to change the way i code - if you can't/don't want to help because of that - rather not comment then

Comment: You learn programming by example. Any example I've ever seen in a text book, tutorial or forum uses these standards. If you want us to help then you need to post code that is readable and understandable. The more you make an effort to do this, the more we are willing to help. Given it is your first day you would think you would be willing to listen to advice since this standards exist for a reason, which you may not yet understand. You should spend more time working on creating your SSCCE if you want help, instead of making comments like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `paintComponent` method of the component you want to custom paint. Draw on its `Graphics` object.

Comment: hi - it worked an hour ago - and i didn't override the paintConponent. I just can't see what i changed, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @AidenStrydom, It could be a concurrency-related issue. Regardless, please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org)

Comment: sorry - i don't understand: sscce?

Comment: @AidenStrydom, Did you follow the link? The explanation is therein.

Comment: thanks a lot - that link help me with asking questions a lot.

food for thought